# CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT constant is missing in opencv `cv2` python module

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, attributeerror

How to access to `CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT` from opencv in python?
I tried this:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('myvideo.avi')
frames_count, fps, width, height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT), cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS), cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
```

And this:

```
import cv2
import cv
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('myvideo.avi')
frames_count, fps, width, height = cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT), cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS), cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
```

and also this:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('myvideo.avi')
frames_count, fps, width, height = cap.get(cv2.cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT), cap.get(cv2.cv.CAP_PROP_FPS), cap.get(cv2.cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), cap.get(cv2.cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT'
```

I'm using **python 2.7.5** and **OpenCV 2.4.9**.

Comment: opencv3.0 will have the proper cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT (and also will discard the deprecated cv submodule)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The constants in the first version of OpenCV python module have a `CV_` prefix. You could thus either use `cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT` or `cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT`.

Comment: It seems to work, but... I'm quite bewildered. Why aren't those constants defined in the `cv2` module?

Comment: In OpenCV 2.x, it appears that the constants are of the form `cv2.cv.CV_CAP_X`, while in OpenCV 3.x, they are `cv2.CAP_X`

Comment: Bad API, bad OpenCV.

Answer (score 17):

While running macports on OSX (opencv @3.0.0_1+python27+tbb)

You can get CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT and CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH with the following:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python
import cv2 
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture()
# set frame width and height
vcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 480)
vcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 640)
vcap.open(0)
```

Answer (score 5):

In OpenCV 2.x, these attributes are named starting with `CV_...` like `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT`.

In OpenCV 3.x **and OpenCV 4.x**,  these attributes are named without `CV_...` like `CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT`.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get

```
#3. CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH
print "\t CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH:     ",cap.get(3)
#4. CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT
print "\t CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT:    ",cap.get(4)
```

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set

```
#3. CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH
cap.set(3,320)
#4. CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT
cap.set(4,240)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import cv2

import cv2.cv as cv
```

## Using cv2:

```
stream = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)

print stream.get(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
```